# How to get a pdb file of a single atom?

Tags: biophysics, pdb

I am trying to get a pdb file that contains a single atom, it doesn't matter if it's Hydrogen or another atom. How can I obtain this? Are there any pdb files with just a single atom available to download? Or do I have to take an existing molecule and remove the atoms manually?

Comment: How do you want to make a crystall of a single atom?

Comment: I have no idea why you would need sth like that, but you'd have to cut existing one

Comment: I'm currently working on a problem on molecular modeling and our software is having problems. I was told that a good way to debug this is to run the program using a pdf file with just a single atom

Comment: `you'd have to cut existing one` can you explain how?

Comment: @user4352158 In the PDB file you can remove every other entry except an atom. You can also view a single atom without altering the file itself(at least in swiss-pdb viewer)